# Enable Remote Desktop in Windows Server Container

Tags: docker, windows-container, windows-server-container

I have a Windows Server container and I want to RDP into its desktop environment. It seems that Microsoft has closed the RDP in recent Windows Server Core Containers.

I tried to follow up on this [tutorial](https://withinrafael.com/2018/03/09/using-remote-desktop-services-in-containers/). I can successfully log in with the Remote Desktop app, but after that, nothing happens. It seems that there is no desktop, or maybe there is another problem.

I was wondering if there are any official Windows Server images where one can access its desktop GUI, or if there is any other way to add this feature.

Comment: Cross referencing: similar question for Win10 container: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66153861/enable-remote-desktop-on-windows-10-container