# Can I run a GUI in a Windows container?

Tags: windows, docker, user-interface, interface, labview

I want to create a Windows container to use LabVIEW and experiment with it. I would like to know if there is a way to open a graphical user interface (GUI) while using the container. I am aware that Linux containers have interfaces for this, but I haven't come across any similar options for Windows containers. Could you please verify this information?

I'am using mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2-amd64.

I haven't tried anything yet because I haven't found any options specifically for Windows containers. I have only come across solutions for Linux containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDP: install a remote desktop server inside the container and access it from the host or other machines using an RDP client

Comment: OK, I'm going to look for information. If you know of any guides or anything, I would appreciate it.

Comment: From what I have seen, in Windows containers, we still cannot use RDP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66153861/enable-remote-desktop-on-windows-10-container